# Trying to validate the linearity of a function based on the linear function definition: f(ax1 + bx2) = af(x1) + bf(x2)

Tags: linear-algebra

This should be a high school math problem, but here we are :) I was refreshing some Linear Algebra definitions and then I came across this one,

f(ax1 + bx2) = af(x1) + bf(x2)

Fairly enough, I tried to have a quick side note proof/example for f(x) = 2x + 3;

So left side gives us: f(ax1 + bx2) = 2(ax1) + 2(bx2) + 3;

and the right side: a(2x1) + 3 + b(2x2) + 3 = 2(ax1) + 2(bx2) + 6;

Therefore left side is **NOT** equal to the right side.

Where my arythmetic went wrong there?

Comment: This is because f(x) = 2x+3 is not a linear transformation.

Note that for linear transformation, it is necessarily true that f(0) = 0

(Though it is a "linear function" in terms of functions...)

Comment: Sorry for late reply and thank you for your response. Yes, I had come to that same conclusion on my own,  otherwise the entire linear algebra could have not have been build on faulty assumptions :) :) I wish that had put this condition on a side note or something,  it's so counterintuitive though, made me scratch my head thinking "what's the magic trick" :) :)